# I am getting this errors “cmdline tools component is missing” I have installed flutter and android studio, how to solve them, or what has to be done?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-doctor

[here is the Doctor Summary][1]

cmdline-tools component is missing
Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqbIw.png

Comment: Find the path to your sdkmanager and run that command you posted

Answer (score 1):

Open Android Studio then settings
then do as the picture shows, done.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the the Sdk folder besides the Android Studio folder: it should have a cmdline-tools folder inside.
If not install it by:
Open your android studio> tools> system settings> android sdk> select android sdk command line tools,  ..build tools, ..sdk platform tools, ..sdk tools > Click OK.
Also take a note of the sdk installation location given on top. You might need it further.

Next, Have you added the following environment variables : ANDROID_HOME, ANDROID_SDK_ROOT, JAVA_HOME correctly?

Next, add the location of the platform tools folder to environment variable `PATH`.

The platform tools folder is installed along with android studio, in the Sdk folder besides Android Studio folder. ("C:\Android\Sdk\platform-tools")

Finally, run flutter doctor --android-licenses to accept the license conditions.

**Please post the result of `flutter doctor -v` from a command prompt if you need further help.**