# Flutter doctor --android-licenses not finding sdkmanager without Android Studio

Tags: flutter, ubuntu-16.04, android-sdk-manager, avd-manager

I'm trying to get my very first Flutter application up and running. When I ran `flutter doctor` it was saying that I was missing Android SDK, so I installed sdkmanager and ran:

```
sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platform;android-29" "build-tools;28.0.3"
```

From there I ran `flutter config --android-sdk /opt/android-sdk`

I got an error saying that I'm missing cmdline-tools, however I don't have Android Studio and don't want to as well. So I went on Android Studio's website and downloaded a manual cmdline-tools and moved the file to android-sdk. OK so far so good, right? No, now I needed to run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` and it's saying Android sdkmanager not found. Why? Is there something I'm missing? I'm doing all of this in Ubuntu.

- Below is the image of flutter doctor status
- Shows me running flutter doctor --android-licenses
- As well as shows the path to the android-sdk in the terminal
- I have as well set flutter config --android-sdk to the correct path
  and is the reason why flutter doctor has no issues with finding the
  android-sdk

[Image!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ITSo.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69164282/13984728  this is what you searching for... its a duplicate question

Answer (score 0):

`Android toolchain - develop` for `Android` devices X `cmdline-tools` component is missing run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`

This error means your `"Android SDK Command-line Tools` are missing"

1. Open Android Studio
2. In the Menu bar , click Tools(4th last)
3. choose SDK Tools panel
4. Tick Android SDK Command-line Tools
5. Click Apply at bottom of the window

Comment: Im using linux and dont want to install android studio. I have tried running 'path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest". Doesnt work. I think this is because im on unix shell.

Comment: but the android studio should be present for flutter development , please show your `flutter doctor` status

Comment: I have updated the OP to contain the image of my OS with both the terminal showing the android-sdk path and displaying that I have accepted the license in cmdline-tools

Answer (score 0):

I gave up and just downloaded android studio using snap package manager and within android studio I did the steps discussed above.

After downloading cmdline-tools from android studio. I have just set the android config --android-sudio-dir "toMyAndroidStudioPath" example. /home/myName/Android/Sdk....

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).