# How do I fix errors in installing Flutter?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code

I am facing these errors and I do not know how to fix them I installed Flutter properly, then I installed android studio and it gives me those errors at android studio, including after I installed plugings, and neither visual studio sees it although it was installed[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeUJj.jpg)

Please give me some ideas what I could do.

Comment: Please do not post errors nor code as an image. Edit the post and add it as a quote or code block.

Answer (score 0):

[cmdtoolline error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69110608/flutter-doctor-results-with-cmdline-tools-component-is-missing)

[Android license unknown error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48604914/flutter-run-error-you-have-not-accepted-the-license-agreements)

For the third error, you have to install vs code or you can skip it if you are using android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Open **Android Studio** -> **SDK Manager** -> **SDK Tools** -> install **Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)**.

then in Terminal execute
**flutter doctor --android-licenses**

Comment: **flutter doctor --android-licenses** then press **y** to accept all the license.

Comment: Thank you, went to fix the error with android studio, but at visual studio although I have it installed gives me error that it is not installed.

Comment: Vs code could be no included in 'Path' variable so you need to check PATH Environment Variable and include VS code to it and try flutter doctor again

Comment: It was automatically included in my path, when I checked the era, and I also installed the Flutter and dart libraries in vs Code and it gives me the same error.